Display count of files group by year
I'm not Unix / Linux person so struggling with command / script which could give me count of files in a directory, and within it multiple sub-directories.
I want to generate output similar to below format
Year Dir Sub-Dir (if present) Count (don't include child directories count)
E.g.:
Year Dir  Sub-Dir (if present)  Count
2021 root -                     1000
2021 root root/child1            100
2021 root root/child1/subchild1   10
2021 root root/child1/subchild1/{and so on}
2022 root -                       50
2022 root root/child1             10
2022 root root/child1/subchild1   1
2022 root root/child1/subchild1/{and so on}
and so on...

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Edit:

There won't be more than 2-3 sub-directories but can restrict to max 3.
Year would be when file was created.
Count is needed only for the files within the directory.
Exclude links or hidden files

It's Linux box, running Red Hat v7.9 if that helps

Please [edit] your question and add a bit  more detail. How many levels down should we go? If there are hundreds of subdirs, should we show hundreds? Thousands? What is the year? Where should we take it from? Last modification of the subdirectory we are looking at? Creation date? Something else? Do we count directories or only files? What about links? Hidden files? Special files (devices, fifos etc)? What operating system are you using? Is this on a Linux machine or a Unix one? Something else?

If a file is hard-linked in multiple directories, should it be counted multiple times?

Could be something like:
LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -path './*/*/*' -type f \
  -printf '%TY/%p\0' |
  perl -F/ -0lane '
    BEGIN{$" = "/"}
    $c{$F[0]}->{$F[1]}++;
    $c{$F[0]}->{"@F[1..2]"}++;
    $c{$F[0]}->{"@F[1..3]"}++;
    END {
      for $y (sort keys %c) {
        for $d (sort keys %{$c{$y}}) {
          printf "%4d %-30s %d\n", $y, $d, $c{$y}->{$d}
        }
      }
    }'

Which gives a break down of years for all regular non-hidden files at depth 3 or deeper for ., and each ./child and ./child/grandchild.
That's assuming GNU find, and using the last-modification time of the file, which can be seen as the creation time of its contents. You can replace %T with %B for the birth time, but not all systems / file systems record that, and GNU find supports retrieving it on few systems, and that particular timestamp is generally not useful.

The OP also wants the info for files that are less than depth 3, they just said they are OK with excluding files at a depth >3 so the inverse of this. Maybe just use -maxdepth instead of -mindepth?

@terdon, the OP's requirements are unclear to me, so I'll leave it as is until they're clarified.

These seem to be clearly spelled out: "1. There won't be more than 2-3 sub-directories but can restrict to max 3." We can also see in their example output that they show values for depth 1, 2 and 3.

I'd say this calls for the following algorithm:

go through all paths to regular files in the current directory and all its subdirectories. For each of these paths

get the creation year
get the directory part of the path
concatenate year and directory and append that to a file (e.g. 2023root/child1)


sort that file
count the occurrences of each line

So, in short, something like (this is zsh, with bash you'll need globstar and check the type of glob * matches yourself):
#!/usr/bin/zsh

# make sure we get the creation time in a reliable format
LANG=C
for file in **/*(.); do
  # get the creation date, like 2024-12-11 10:01:12.111242 +0100
  # then cut out only things before the first `-`
  year="$(stat -c %y "${file}" | grep -o '^[^-]*')"
  printf '%s\t%s\0' ${year} "${file:h}"
done | sort | uniq -c

(this assumes directory names do not contain newlines.)
You can then use awk or similar to transform the output to bring it into the exact shape you want. Note that your dir column is fully redundant, and the subdir column is what I'd keep.
The alternative that I'd probably go with is to just write a quick python program that implements the above algorithm, and instead of a file simply uses a simple collections.defaultdict to keep track of modification date / directory tuples. Something like (untested! top of my head!)
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

yeardirs = defaultdict(int)
for dir, dirs, files in Path(".").walk():
  for filename in files:
    birthtime = (dir / filename).stat().st_birthtime
    birthyear = datetime.fromtimestamp(birthtime).year
    yeardirs[(birthyear, str(dir))] += 1

print(f"|{'year':>4s}|{'Directory':<40s}|{'Count':>6s}|")
print(f"|{'':–>4s}|{'':–<40s}|{'':–>6s}|")
for yeardir, count in sorted(yeardirs.items()):
  year, dir = yeardir
  print(f"|{year:>4d}|{dir[:40]:<40s}|{count:>6d}|")
print(f"|{'':–>4s}|{'':–<40s}|{'':–>6s}|")


Note that zsh has its own builtin stat (which predates both GNU and BSD stat) in the zsh/stat module. zmodload zsh/stat; stat -LF%Y -A year +mtime -- $file to get the year of the mtime in $year for instance.

@marcus-müller thanks, I will check and update.
